# JavaScript; highlight all occurrences of a particular string in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, highlight

Let's say I have this code:

```
<textarea style="width:300px;height:200px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do ipsum eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ipsum ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in ipsum reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur ipsum sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit ipsum anim id est laborum.</textarea>
```

I want to highlight all occurrences of the string `ipsum`. I already googled but only found scripts that highlight a single occurrence only.

Does anybody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a plugin that tokenize your textarea content into balise;
See http://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/